# ggplot2 grouping legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `trajectory_df` that has the following structure:

[image: table]

The `uid` row has 6 different possible values, each representing a particular user. So I want to plot 6 lines on the same plot, and I'm currently doing it in this way:

```
ggplot(trajectory_df, aes(Month, Pagerank, colour=uid, group=uid)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_x_discrete(breaks=month_ticks)
```

Which gives me this picture:

[image: the graph]

Which is just what I want, except for the legend. I want there to be 6 different entries in the legend, not a colorful range of values.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Make your uid variable a factor, right now it's numeric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ggplot(trajectory_df, aes(Month, Pagerank, colour=factor(uid), group=uid)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_x_discrete(breaks=month_ticks)
```